# How to get input into Google Sheets App Script without user intervention?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm hoping to migrate an application for tracking samples from Microsoft Word/Excel to Google Apps, as we have a number of users and having the Excel sheet be locked all the time is causing problems.

However, the current script is dependent on having an input box pop up asking for input that closes automatically when return/enter is input. This works well because most of the input is supplied by using barcode scanners that automatically send  after the input from the scan.

In trying to migrate the script, I've found that the Google version of inputbox won't accept  to process input. I can't have the users go to click "OK" with every scan, as they may scan 10-12 barcodes at a time and clicking in between each would significantly slow down the process.

Does anyone have ideas on how I could replicate that functionality? I've tried making a test HTML form and specifying "autofocus" on the button, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: @Hi, Michael! I did not understand fully what you're trying to achieve in apps script. As far as it looks yout don't know much about apps script documentation and its functionalities. So, here's my suggestion. Record a macro of desired functionalities in sheets and them analyse the script generated from it. After recording click in "EDIT Script". Google Apps Scrtipt is based in modern Java Script. [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). Best wishes! Hint: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm trying to get input from users with the dialog box dismissed and script execution continued with a <CR> from the user. The relevant Google feature request is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/145721806

I'm just wondering if anyone knows a workaround for this until Google implements the request.

Answer (score 1):

I know the workaround provided is not useful to you, but I'm leaving an answer just in case someone faces the same issue.

As seen in the comments, there is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/145721806) where Sheets does not autofocus the [prompt](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) windows, so pressing Enter doesn't act on any button. The current workaround is to press "Tab" to focus it.